# Sample Inclusion Criteria for an Intent-To-Treat Analysis in an Encouragement Design With One-Sided Non-Compliance

Tags: inference, experiment-design, causality, treatment-effect

This question is about how to define the sample in an Intent-To-Treat analysis of an experiment with balanced pre-assignment and an encouragement design. This is a bit different than the usual setting with perfect compliance in exposure, so bear with me.

Here's my setup. Suppose there is a group of size $N$ that is the population of interest (based on some criteria) that is split into treatment and control. Each member is pre-assigned to a experimental arm. A balancing test using baseline data is performed to confirm that groups are comparable at randomization time, perhaps with some re-randomization needed to achieve that balance.

The treatment is an encouragement design with imperfect one-sided compliance (say being told about the benefits of wearing masks on top of a general explanation of COVID, the control group received only the latter). I care about the causal effect of being told about the benefits of masks, rather than the effect of actually wearing them.

Unfortunately, only $N'<N$ folks are exposed to the encouragement and/or lecture since people need to go to a place where that happens, and not everyone does. We can assume that the treatment does not influence the attendance margin, the outcome is perfectly observable for all $N$ users, and SUTVA is maintained (no interference between units).

I have two questions:

1. In calculating $E[Y \vert T] - E[Y \vert C]$, do we use $N$ observations or $N<N'$ that were exposed to the experiment?
2. Which is the policy relevant group here for the cost-benefit analysis?

My intuition is that while using $N$ dilutes the effect and [worsens efficiency](https://www.evanmiller.org/lazy-assignment-and-ab-testing.html) of the test, that seems like the appropriate group for the ATE calculation and weighing the costs and benefits of the program. Moreover, the balance check applies to the original $N$-randomization, so that favors using $N$ as well.